# how to update Listview while at the end of Listview scrolling in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to display the listview from sqlite. At the end of Listview I want to load next 10 data from sqlite and this process will continue till data ends in SQLite. But the issue is data load at first time successfully and when i scroll 3rd time page/data does not load and after LocalListPageIndex= 2 then progress bar is continuously running.

Here is my Code of ListView Scrolling.

```
 listView.removeFooterView(progressBar);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

            lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if (X != firstVisibleItem) {
                if (LocalListPageIndex <= 5) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Last Item." + lastInScreen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (lastInScreen == totalItemCount) {

                        listView.addFooterView(progressBar);

                        // Execute some code after 15 seconds have passed
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                LocalListPageIndex += 1;

                                int OFFSET_SCROLL = 10
                                List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions(OFFSET_SCROLL);
                                for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc) {
                                    descArray.add(all_Post);
                                }
                                if (adapter != null) {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                   // adapter = new AllPostAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    //listView.invalidateViews();
                                    listView.setSelection(totalItemCount);

                                }
                            }
                        }, 15000);
                    }

                }   if (LocalListPageIndex == 5)  {
                    Log.e("hide footer", "footer hide");
                    listView.removeFooterView(progressBar);
                }
            }
            X = firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using RecyclerView: 
The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. This widget is a container for displaying large data sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views. Use the RecyclerViewwidget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events.

A layout manager positions item views inside a RecyclerView and determines when to reuse item views that are no longer visible to the user. To reuse (or recycle) a view, a layout manager may ask the adapter to replace the contents of the view with a different element from the dataset. Recycling views in this manner improves performance by avoiding the creation of unnecessary views or performing expensivefindViewById() lookups 
Example:

Add this view to your layout:

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Once you have added a RecyclerView widget to your layout, obtain a handle to the object, connect it to a layout manager, and attach an adapter for the data to be displayed:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        // Set your myDataSet with the url of your images.
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    ...
}
```

Create an adapter to manage the recycler view:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private MySQLClass mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(MySQLClass myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        textView.setText(mDataset.get(i));

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

info from:

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with retrieving the data from the database its better to use loaders.A loader will load all the details depending upon your query and give it to you in the form of a Cursor.Now you can simply give that cursor to CursorAdapter(if you are using Cursor adapter)or you can extract the data from cursor to a list and give that list to normal adapter.